# Understanding ANOVA for comparison of models in R. Why is the result the same regardless of model order?

Tags: r, regression, anova

I'm trying to figure out why the `anova` function in R gives me the same results (for the p-value) regardless of the order of the models.

```
> anova(lm.fit ,lm.fit2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: medv ~ lstat
Model 2: medv ~ lstat + I(lstat^2)
  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq     F    Pr(>F)    
1    504 19472                                 
2    503 15347  1    4125.1 135.2 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> anova(lm.fit2,lm.fit)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: medv ~ lstat + I(lstat^2)
Model 2: medv ~ lstat
  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq     F    Pr(>F)    
1    503 15347                                 
2    504 19472 -1   -4125.1 135.2 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I can't understand why the p-value is so low in both cases. The way I'm understanding I should interpret the result of the `anova` is that the model 2 is better than model 1 if the p-value is very low, but in this case I'm getting exactly the same no matter the order.

I'm trying to read `?anova` to check what this all means, but the help page is very succinct, is there another help where it states what the `Df` parameter means for instance?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept "degrees of freedom" in a statistical test?

Comment: I see different results: the second comparison yields a negative "Sum of Sq" value as well as a negative DF, neither of which are mathematically possible in a correct ANOVA application.  It's harmless--the magnitudes are correct--but I believe the user of `anova` is expected to order the arguments in a meaningful way.

Comment: @EdM Yes, I am. (edit): Although now I'm not sure cause I'm not used to see negative degree of freedom. I was looking at them like I look in physics, the difference between the number of parameters in the observables and the degrees of the fitting model.

Comment: @whuber Yes, but I can't understand what that means about the hypotesis that Model 1 fits the training data better than Model 2 or vice versa. I'm being told to look at the p-value but in both cases it gives the same probability.

Comment: As it should.  If you're unsure how to interpret p-values, take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31.  A search on [nested F test](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nested+F+test) also turns up many threads you might find of interest.